# How can I use ruby flat_map to map to tuples of children AND parent

Tags: ruby

Imagine you have an array of objects called `parents` and each entry is an instance of a `Parent`.  And imagine each parent has a method called `children` which returns an array of `Child` instances.  Now imagine you want to flat_map from the parents to the children but in a later step you will still need access to the parent (for, say, filtering or whatever).  How would you do it?

```rb
parents
  .flat_map { |parent| parent.children.map { |child| {parent: parent, child: child} } }
```

Would give me what I need, but... eww.  Surely there's a more ruby-esque way of doing this?  It almost seems like an RX merge or combineLatest.  Can't figure out a ruby way of doing this other than what I already have.

Here's a bit of ruby to generate the parent/child structure I'm talking about using random data:

```rb
class Child ; end

class Parent
  attr_reader :children

  def initialize(children)
    @children = children || []
  end
end

parents = 100.times.map do
  Parent.new(rand(10).times.map { Child.new })
end
```

Comment: Do you have a workable example of your data?

Comment: No, but this would give you a workable set:

```
class Child ; end

class Parent
  attr_reader :children

  def initialize(children)
    @children = children || []
  end
end

parents = 100.times.map do
  Parent.new(rand(10).times.map { Child.new })
end
```

Comment: SO won't let me forward that in a sane way.  Hopefully it makes sense.  Any half-decent IDE should be able to format that pretty easily.

Comment: Perhaps you should [edit] your question with the added informations

Comment: Done, but I had also linked to a gist and SO appears to have lost that comment.

Answer (score 1):

Consider adopting the following structure.

```
class Child
  attr_accessor :name # create accessor for name of child

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

```
class Parent
  @families = {} # create class instance variable

  class << self  # change self to singleton class
    attr_reader :families # create accessor for @families
  end

  def initialize(name, children)
    self.class.families[name] = children.map { |name| Child.new(name) }
  end
end
```

```
Parent.new("Bob and Diane",     %w| Hector Lois Rudolph |)
  #=> #<Parent:0x00005ac0ddad9aa0> 
Parent.new("Hank and Trixie",   %w| Phoebe |)
  #=> #<Parent:0x00005ac0ddb252c0> 
Parent.new("Thelma and Louise", %w| Zaphod Sue |)
  #=> #<Parent:0x00005ac0ddcb2890>
```

```
Parent.families
  #=> {"Bob and Diane"    =>[#<Child:0x00005ac0ddadf9f0 @name="Hector">,
  #                          #<Child:0x00005ac0ddadf388 @name="Lois">,
  #                          #<Child:0x00005ac0ddadf1a8 @name="Rudolph">], 
  #    "Hank and Trixie"  =>[#<Child:0x00005ac0ddb251d0 @name="Phoebe">],
  #    "Thelma and Louise"=>[#<Child:0x00005ac0ddcb27c8 @name="Zaphod">,
  #                          #<Child:0x00005ac0ddcb27a0 @name="Sue">]}
```

```
Parent.families.keys
  #=> ["Bob and Diane", "Hank and Trixie", "Thelma and Louise"]
```

```
Parent.families["Bob and Diane"].map { |child| child.name }
  #=> ["Hector", "Lois", "Rudolph"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I'm asking for.  Mapping is easy.  I'm asking for a ruby-esque way (better than what I've already posted) to flat_map from a parent to a collection of tuples that contain both the parent we started with and *each* child so that the next stage in the pipeline has both to work with.

Comment: In that case I don’t understand the question or your reference to a “pipeline”. Considering that mine is the only answer six hours after you posted the question, I don’t think I’m alone in that regard. You need to edit the question to clarify want you are trying to do.

Comment: By pipeline I just mean the set of operations through which the data passes.  I tend to use the lazy version of the enum most of the time to avoid multiple loops, and so if I map, then select, then flat_map, then call .first or something each one of those method calls is one stage in the pipeline.  What I want is to flat_map from A to A+B so I can use A and B in later stages.  This would be something like a combineLatest (though not exactly) in RxJS.